# Google App Engine host routing

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy an Google App engine app with this setup:

```
www.domain.com -> Wordpress Frontend
app.domain.com -> AngularJS Backend
api.domain.com -> Rest API used by Angular Backend
```

Can I achieve this using the basic app schema? Or should I use the [modules API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/)?

My main worry about using modules is that they use different instances, increasing the billing. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Modules API is your best bet in this case. You can set [automatic scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/modules/#PHP_Instance_scaling_and_class) to all modules so that new instances are only spun up when there's requests.

Comment: But it will need two instances up instead of just one to serve the two modules, right? That would increment the monthly bill...

Comment: Yes, if you have requests to both modules simultaneously. It's a trade-off for modular code.

Answer (score 1):

It's completely up to you...

- Depending on how you structure your project you could do it in either way but of course with Modules things would be a lot nicer organized, although yes, it would increase your monthly bill, while with a single `default` module your bill would likely to be smaller but your code organization - messier.
- If "**api.domain.com -> Rest API used by Angular Backend**" uses any backend language other than PHP (Wordpress) then you would have to run them as two separate modules/projects since you cannot have both PHP and Python/Java/Go runtimes on the same instance.
- If your "**app.domain.com -> AngularJS Backend**" part consists of static files only and no backend code (php/python/go/java) then that wouldn't require running instances as everything would be served from Google's frontend servers and not directly from your instances (the static files are normally not even included with the code you deploy unless you specify that you want that in `app.yaml`).